# Deleting a MYSQL row with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

so I am having this code for a guestbook:

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
 <td><strong>View Guestbook | <a href="gbook.php">Sign Guestbook</a> </strong></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($_POST['username'] == "admin" && $_POST['password'] == "pietje"){
        echo 'Welkom';
        $loggedIn = true;
        echo '<img width="500" height="375" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/southpark/images/9/9e/Party.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140712092024">';

    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect user or pass';
        echo '<img width="500" height="375" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/B1TMcmoBAaSZi/giphy.gif">';
    }
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}  

  ?>

<form id='login' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

<input type='submit' name='login' value='login' />

</fieldset>
</form>

<?php

 $host="mysql17.000webhost.com"; // Host name 
$username="a1126203_stan"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="a1126203_gb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 ?>

 <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
 <tr>
 <td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <tr>
 <td>ID</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="117">Name</td>
 <td width="14">:</td>
 <td width="357"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Email</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">Comment</td>
 <td valign="top">:</td>
 <td><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">Date/Time </td>
 <td valign="top">:</td>
 <td><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 $id = $rows['id'];
 echo $id;
 if($loggedIn){
 echo '<tr>
 <td width="100"> </td>
 <td>
 <input name="delete'.$id.'" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
 </td>
 </tr>';
 }
 if(isset($_POST['delete'.$id]))
         {

 $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

            $sql="DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE id='".$id."'";
            mysql_select_db('a1126203_gb');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval )
            {
               die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            echo "Deleted data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);
         }                   
 ?>
 </table>
<?php
if($loggedIn){

}
 }
 mysql_close(); //close database
 ?>
```

Iknow it's ugly written but that doesn't really matter atm, I am making a delete button for every new row but I want to delete the row that has the same id as the delete button. But for some (probably obvious) reason it doesn't work.

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `myql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statement instead. Check for errors after you call an sql command.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to my question

Comment: @StanVanDerBend Even though it's irrelevant  to your question but it's not a good practice to use the depreciated functions because you may not get any kind of help in the future and PDO will help you to prevent from SQL injections and from other vulnerabilities

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @KenY-N I am not getting any reaction upon clicking the delete button, well it just doesn't do anything

Comment: The delete submit button isn't inside a form.

Comment: @BenSwinburne Lol I am so dumb, thanks a lot

Comment: @Stan Van Der Bend
Please, accept Ben Swinburne's answer if it fixed your problem.
About Jen's comment : actually, "Check for errors after you call an sql command." was relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete button isn't inside a form so it won't submit when clicked.

Place the input fields inside a `<form>` tag and they'll work,

```
<form method="post" action="http://some/url">
    <input name="delete'.$id.'" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
create separate form like

```
<form method="post" id='form' action="http://some/url">
    <input type="hidden" id="deleteId">
 </form>
```

your code

```
<input name="delete'.$id.'" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
```

replace with

```
<input type="button" onclick=delete(.$id.) value="Delete">
```

and

```
<script>
function delete(id){
  $('#deleteId').val(id);
  $('#form').submit();
}
</script>
```